# How do i access my database from Spotify apps

Tags: php, database, spotify

Okey so I am building a spotify app and I will need access to my MySQL database in this app both getting and inserting data to it, now spotify don't support PHP witch I would normally use for this so how do I work around this? I have no idea how to do this without using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotify API uses JavaScript and you can use for example jQuery framework with it. Just save
jquery.js to your addon-folder and include it in your script. Then you can use $.post() and others to save/retrieve data from your external server.

Comment: Okey so I can use ajax to post or get information from the server. But wont the page the ajax call acces need to be in PHP? or could I have a php file on my server to do what I need and just request that from the spotify app? like:                          `$.get('theFileOnTheServer.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});`

Comment: On your server you can use whatever language you like. Your example should work just fine.